# How to use if-else in pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have started learning pandas and got stumbled at the below problem:

Following is a table which has data like:

Book:

```
B_IDX B_NAME B_AUTHOR B_PRICE B_UTYPE B_ID
1     ABC    aaa      12.21   SCI     182
2     BCD    bbb      98      ECN     920
3     CDE    ccc      22.34   SCI     228
4     DEF    ddd      44.11   LIT     761
5     EFG    eee      0.99    MAT     10242
6     FGH    fff      4.99    MAT     77721
```

UCODE:

```
U_ID  U_CD
182   9982825
950   9992822
228   9999983
776   9912876
332   9003931
```

The requirement is to use the if..else logic to pull the data from the above mentioned tables.

Req.:

```
if B_UTYPE == 'SCI':
     pull the record from 'UCODE'
elif  B_UTYPE == 'MAT':
     split the  B_ID in 4 and 1 digits i.e. B_UTYPE.split[:2] and B_UTYPE.split[3:5]
else:
    keep the data as it is.
```

Excepted O/P:

```
B_ID B_NAME B_AUTHOR B_PRICE B_UTYPE B_ID   U_ID    U_CD      N_COL1  N_COL2
1    ABC    aaa      12.21   SCI     182    182     9982825   NA      NA
2    BCD    bbb      98      ECN     920    NA      NA        NA      NA
3    CDE    ccc      22.34   SCI     228    228     9999983   NA      NA
4    DEF    ddd      44.11   LIT     761    NA      NA        NA      NA 
5    EFG    eee      0.99    MAT     10242  NA      NA        102     42
6    FGH    fff      4.99    MAT     77721  NA      NA        777     21
```

Any help/tutorial where I can get some insight to achieve the expected output by meeting the above conditions?

Comment: You have two columns with the same name in your `Book` dataframe? Is that intended?

Comment: @rahlf23 Thanks, corrected it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For readability sake, build each result separately and then concatenate the pieces together.

```
u_id = df.B_ID.astype(str).where(df.B_UTYPE.eq('SCI'))
u_cd = df.B_ID.map(ucode.set_index('U_ID').U_CD.astype(str))
ncol = (df.B_ID.astype(str)
          .str.extract(r'(\d{3})(\d+)')
          .where(df.B_UTYPE.eq('MAT'))
          .rename(columns=lambda x: f'N_COL{x+1}'))

df = pd.concat([df, u_id, u_cd, ncol], axis=1)
print(df)

   B_IDX B_NAME B_AUTHOR  B_PRICE B_UTYPE   B_ID B_ID     B_ID N_COL1 N_COL2
0      1    ABC      aaa    12.21     SCI    182  182  9982825    NaN    NaN
1      2    BCD      bbb    98.00     ECN    920  NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
2      3    CDE      ccc    22.34     SCI    228  228  9999983    NaN    NaN
3      4    DEF      ddd    44.11     LIT    761  NaN      NaN    NaN    NaN
4      5    EFG      eee     0.99     MAT  10242  NaN      NaN    102     42
5      6    FGH      fff     4.99     MAT  77721  NaN      NaN    777     21
```

Comment: May I know, Why you're doing "astype(str)" in u_cd = df.B_ID.map(ucode.set_index('U_ID').U_CD.astype(str)) ?

Comment: @Alpha Otherwise the IDs are displayed as floats in scientific notation which isn't what you would've wanted, I'm guessing...

Comment: I am using python 2.7 and getting the below error:

File "<ipython-input-12-6e5bbe00618c>", line 6
    ncol = ncol = (df.B_ID.astype(str)
          .str.extract(r'(\d{3})(\d+)')
          .where(df.B_UTYPE.eq('MAT'))
          .rename(columns=lambda x: f'N_COL{x+1}'))
                                                                                                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax for f'N_COL{x+1}'

Comment: @Alpha Replace `f'N_COL{x+1}'` with `'N_COL{}'.format(x+1)`, f-strings are not available on older python versions.

Comment: That was helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

This is a two step approach.  First, you need to figure out which rows match which condition.  Then once you have your conditions and outputs, you can use masking and `assign` to add the series to your DataFrame.

```
c1 = book.B_UTYPE.eq("SCI")
c2 = book.B_UTYPE.eq("MAT")

s1 = book.B_ID.map(ucode.set_index('U_ID').U_CD)
s2 = book.B_ID.astype(str)
```

Now for the fun part:

```
parts = {
    'U_ID': book.B_ID.mask(~c1),
    'U_CD': pd.Series(s1).mask(~c1),
    'N_COL1': s2.str[:3].mask(~c2),
    'N_COL2': s2.str[3:].mask(~c2)      
}

book.assign(**parts)
```

```
   ID B_NAME B_AUTHOR  B_PRICE B_UTYPE   B_ID   U_ID       U_CD N_COL1 N_COL2
0   1    ABC      aaa    12.21     SCI    182  182.0  9982825.0    NaN    NaN
1   2    BCD      bbb    98.00     ECN    920    NaN        NaN    NaN    NaN
2   3    CDE      ccc    22.34     SCI    228  228.0  9999983.0    NaN    NaN
3   4    DEF      ddd    44.11     LIT    761    NaN        NaN    NaN    NaN
4   5    EFG      eee     0.99     MAT  10242    NaN        NaN    102     42
5   6    FGH      fff     4.99     MAT  77721    NaN        NaN    777     21
```

---

***Setup*** so you can reproduce:

```
book = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, 5: 6},
 'B_NAME': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'BCD', 2: 'CDE', 3: 'DEF', 4: 'EFG', 5: 'FGH'},
 'B_AUTHOR': {0: 'aaa', 1: 'bbb', 2: 'ccc', 3: 'ddd', 4: 'eee', 5: 'fff'},
 'B_PRICE': {0: 12.21, 1: 98.0, 2: 22.34, 3: 44.11, 4: 0.99, 5: 4.99},
 'B_UTYPE': {0: 'SCI', 1: 'ECN', 2: 'SCI', 3: 'LIT', 4: 'MAT', 5: 'MAT'},
 'B_ID': {0: 182, 1: 920, 2: 228, 3: 761, 4: 10242, 5: 77721}})

ucode = pd.DataFrame({'U_ID': {0: 182, 1: 950, 2: 228, 3: 776, 4: 332},
 'U_CD': {0: 9982825, 1: 9992822, 2: 9999983, 3: 9912876, 4: 9003931}})
```